# Does `git merge -s ours` trump normal merges?

Tags: git, merge

In [git](http://git-scm.com/), what would the expected behaviour be if I have a commit that was merged into two branches using different merge strategies, and then I later merge those two branches together?

I want to know which branches' actual changes end up in the resulting branch, and why.

I'm specifically interested in the behaviour of [`git merge -s ours`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) compared to normally merged commits.

I did a quick experiment, and in this oversimplified example, the branch that has a skipped commit (as in "appears in the logs, but the patches are omitted") due to `git merge -s ours` always wins (which is the behaviour I want), but I'm not sure if I can rely on that (assuming there were no further potentially clashing edits on the same lines in the file).

```bash
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /sandbox/foo/.git/
$ echo  "qwerty"> foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 1f58b74] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 foo.txt
$ git checkout -b CLEAN_SLATE
Switched to a new branch 'CLEAN_SLATE'
$ git checkout -b FEAT_BRANCH_A
Switched to a new branch 'FEAT_BRANCH_A'
$ git checkout -b FEAT_BRANCH_B
Switched to a new branch 'FEAT_BRANCH_B'
$ git checkout -b ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
Switched to a new branch 'ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH'
$ echo "asdf">> foo.txt
$ git add -u
$ git commit -m "Odd commit"
[ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH ba8aab3] Odd commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git checkout FEAT_BRANCH_A
Switched to branch 'FEAT_BRANCH_A'
$ # skip over odd commit in branch A
$ git merge -m "Merge -s ours of ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH" -s ours ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
Merge made by the 'ours' strategy.
$ # include odd commit in branch B
$ git checkout FEAT_BRANCH_B 
Switched to branch 'FEAT_BRANCH_B'
$ git merge -m "Normal merge of ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH" ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
Updating 1f58b74..ba8aab3
Fast-forward (no commit created; -m option ignored)
 foo.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git checkout master                                          
Switched to branch 'master'                                                                               
$ # experiment one: First merge A, then B                      
$ git merge -m "Merge FEAT_BRANCH_A" FEAT_BRANCH_A
Updating 1f58b74..0c15b0c
Fast-forward (no commit created; -m option ignored)
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   0c15b0c Merge -s ours of ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
|\  
| * ba8aab3 Odd commit
|/  
* 1f58b74 Initial commit
$ cat foo.txt
qwerty
$ git merge -m "Merge FEAT_BRANCH_B" FEAT_BRANCH_B
Already up-to-date.
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   0c15b0c Merge -s ours of ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
|\  
| * ba8aab3 Odd commit
|/  
* 1f58b74 Initial commit
$ cat foo.txt
qwerty
$ # gives qwerty, so A wins.
$ # experiment two: First merge B, then A
$ git reset --hard CLEAN_SLATE
HEAD is now at 1f58b74 Initial commit
$ git merge -m "Merge FEAT_BRANCH_B" FEAT_BRANCH_B
Updating 1f58b74..ba8aab3
Fast-forward (no commit created; -m option ignored)
 foo.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git log --graph --oneline
* ba8aab3 Odd commit
* 1f58b74 Initial commit
$ cat foo.txt
qwerty
asdf
$ git merge -m "Merge FEAT_BRANCH_A" FEAT_BRANCH_A
Updating ba8aab3..0c15b0c
Fast-forward (no commit created; -m option ignored)
 foo.txt | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   0c15b0c Merge -s ours of ODD_COMMIT_BRANCH
|\  
| * ba8aab3 Odd commit
|/  
* 1f58b74 Initial commit
$ cat foo.txt
qwerty
$ # still gives qwerty, so A still wins.
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second experiment, the reason why `FEAT_BRANCH_A` "wins" has little to do with the `ours` merge strategy; the merge is a *fast-forward*, so the differences between the branches are not considered at all.

If you perform the final merge with `--no-ff` to force a three-way merge instead of a fast-forward, the resulting tree is the same, but *why* you get the same tree bears a closer examination.  The *merge-base* for the three-way merge is `ba8aab3 Odd commit` (which is also `HEAD`) and git observes that the difference between `ba8aab3` and `FEAT_BRANCH_A` is:

```
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 0a93b8c..19f0805 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1,2 +1 @@
 qwerty
-asdf
```

This diff arises because you used the `ours` strategy at an earlier time, but git does not know this because information about what strategy was used to produce a merge commit is not recorded.  `FEAT_BRANCH_A` only "wins" in your experiment because that's how the three-way diff looks to git.

To summarise: you can *always* rely on the behaviour of `-s ours` when you are *immediately* using that strategy.  If you are doing a normal three-way merge, the outcome depends on what the diff says, and a fast-forward will just be a fast-forward (unless suppressed with `--no-ff`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the --no-ff issue. The thing that was really throwing me off was not realising that "Odd commit" is the common ancestor (I assumed -s ours would skip over this, which in hindsight is silly!) :) . After doing more reading based on your answer and @jthill's, I think I've finally got the hang of things.

Answer (score 1):

To see the changes merge is working with, do `git diff A...B` and `git diff B...A` (three dots).  That will show the difference between `B` (resp.`A`) and the merge base. How the merge base was produced is irrelevant. Your merge strategy determines how the current differences are reconciled, and that's the end of its own relevance.  If you check your graph against the symmetric diffs that should help with understanding the results.